# Lossless color compression

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, file-formats, colorspace

I need to reduce the file size of an mp4 video. I don't need color information at all but pixel brightness resolution must be preserved. Videos consist of white background with a few (important) black dots of about 5px diameter. I am confused about what the best method/output would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the video properties, my generic answer is

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf geq=lum='p(X,Y)':cb=128:cr=128 out.mp4
```

This will reset the color information, but pass the luma plane intact. Add `-crf 0` for truly lossless re-encoding.

---

This is the faster way,

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf extractplanes=y,format=yuv420p out.mp4
```

The luma plane is extracted, and then neutral chroma planes are added in the pixel format conversion. This 2nd step is added because otherwise ffmpeg will auto-convert pixel format to yuv444 which isn't widely compatible.

Comment: Awesome, that works. Is this the quickest way? If not, what information would need to know for a faster/better solution?

Comment: There's one potentially quicker way but I have to check whether it alters the luma.

Answer (score 2):

Much faster solution: `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf extractplanes=y out.mp4`

Comment: What makes that faster? Can you explain the -vf option so that others can solve their own problems in the future?

Comment: User wants luma plane only, so this command do that efficiently. Also geq filter is GPL and slow in almost any scenario.